# How do I add a leaflet provider to the list of geocoder providers?

Tags: 9

I want configure the Leaflet geocoder provider, but I don't know how.

I have enabled the *Geolocation - Leaflet* sub-module of the [Geolocation Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation) module, but visiting /admin/config/system/geocoder/geocoder-provider, I see an empty list.

> [image: screenshot]

The [list of the geocoder implementations](https://packagist.org/providers/geocoder-php/provider-implementation) doesn't list the Leaflet one. How can I add it?

Answer (score 0):

The *Geolocation - Leaflet* module that is part of the [Geolocation Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation) module is a map provider, a provider that is able to show a map using data provided by a site/API (Google Maps API or [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/), for example). The providers used from the [Geocoder](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder) module (which is the module handling the setting page on /admin/config/system/geocoder/geocoder-provider) obtain a location from other data, for example an IP and the GeoIP database data.

There cannot be a Geocoder Leaflet provider, as Leaflet is for showing a map, not getting a location from other data.